# Soundcloud iframe implementation into bootstrap4 problem

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, soundcloud

[Visit the website](http://jeremybertin.at/1980-house-recordings/dist/index.html)So first thanks a lot for all who will help ! I'm a very beginner so i hope i will be clear enough.

I'm building my website with bootstrap. This is a label music website. I'm at the end. But i have this appearing in my console

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.

So I've been digging a lot into it and I found either it's not working or I'm not sure if I just not understanding it.

I've tried really really a lot of things that will be very long to list ! But the significant thing that worked out it's when i put all the iframes out of any "container" Then it's working PER-FEC-TLY. No more red messages in my console. Now I'm feeling a bit like stupid because i don't know what to do and i don't understand "why it does not work into a container ?" This issue is slowing down the website ...

here is a list of things i have tried:
- Tried with all types of container provided by Bootstrap.
- Tried the embed provided by Bootstrap.
- Disabled mostly everything, switching between my JS and CSS. Everything possible and impossible. 
- Put 0 for padding and margin class from Bootstrap.

Well, i believe that the container thing is the key, for why, I'm too beginner to understand yet and i would like to understand it ...

```html
<div class="container premiere text-left shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="height: 100%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="../images-min/divagar-min.jpg" class="card-img" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 premiere-text">
      <h5>Analog Advisory</h5>
      <p>Cloud One by Divagar</p>
      <p>Released on November 30th 2018 Exclusive Bandcamp.</p>
      <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/532472661&color=%23000000&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&show_artwork=false"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the solution ! Finally i found myself (i'm very proud haha) It was the display and here is a code that imitate (if i can say like this) the display: none. So i can keep all my behavior safe. I hope this will help some others :)

```css
.page {
 /* display: none;
 opacity: 0; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.page.current{
 /* display: block;
 opacity: 1; */
  position: inherit;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow: visible;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
// TRANSITION BETWEEN PAGES NAVBAR TOP
$(function(){
  let request = window.location.hash;

  if(request == "#home" || request == "#releases" || request == "#artists" || request == "#partners" || request == "#about-us"){
    $(".page.current").removeClass("current");

    $(".page").eq(0).addClass("current");
  }

  $("#navbar .nav-clic").on("click", function(){
    // var speed = 800;
    let i = $("#navbar .nav-clic").index(this);
    $(".page.current").animate({opacity: 0, marginLeft:500}, 800, function(){
      $(this).removeClass("current");
      $('.page').eq(i).animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: 0}, 1000).addClass("current");
      // $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
  });
});
```

Peace, cheers and see you soon :)